# Javassist - How to add line number to method

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I am a newbie to java bytecode and javassist. I created a new class file with using javassist. Although I added fields and methods, I couldn't achieve to add line number to method. Result of my research, I understand that I need to add linenumberattribute to codeattribute of method info. Moreover, linenumberattribute consists of linenumbertable. I don't know how can I create a new linenumberattribute with javassist.

Comment: I think that is an interesting question and downvoter should explain his/her reasons.

Comment: The LineNumberTable structure in a class map the bytecode in the class to the lines in the source file. Since you are directly injecting bytecode there are no lines in the source file so to which line would you map? It's because of this that javassist doesn't allow you to create LineNumberAttribute objects (it has no public constructors)... If you really have some kind of scenario where makes sense injecting the line number attribute, please let me know I'm curious. Also I think I have a hack or two that might do the trick if really needed.

Comment: Actually, I does not really need that :) But I am curious about how can I do that. My aim is creating new node entity and graph repository class(we can assume similar thing entity and dao) at runtime. I need to create a new class with javassist and recompile with aspectj. In order to do that, I inspected the compiled java classes which are compiled with spring-data-neo4j aspectj. And then, i realized aspectj can add new line numbers. But, I can't do that with javassist.

Comment: @pabrantes: Javassist allows you to create new methods and even new classes. So why do you think that it is impossible that the description of how to create or manipulate come from a sort of source file? Apache Xalan compiles XSLT documents into byte code so you have a scenario where it makes sense to associate byte code with a source file and line numbers. But they use BCEL…

Comment: @Holger: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. I was just saying that the LineNumberTable usually contains the information for the lines in the source code files. So if you use javassist to create new methods what meaningful information could possibility be put in that LineNumberTable. Your example of Xalan was a good one to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am writing a compiler that produces JVM code. I need line numbers in the output. I do it this way.

I build up a list of objects similar to this:

```
public class MyLineNum {
    public final short pc;
    public final short lineNum;
}
```

Then I add the line number table:

```
final ClassFile  classFile = ...;
final ConstPool  constPool = classFile.getConstPool();
final MethodInfo minfo     = new MethodInfo( ... );
final Bytecode   code      = new Bytecode( constPool );
... code that writes to 'code'

final List<MyLineNum> lineNums = new ArrayList<>();
... code that adds to 'lineNums'

final CodeAttribute codeAttr = code.toCodeAttribute();
if ( !lineNums.isEmpty() ) {
    // JVM spec describes method line number table thus:
    //    u2 line_number_table_length;
    //    { u2 start_pc;
    //      u2 line_number;
    //    } line_number_table[ line_number_table_length ];
    final int    numLineNums = lineNums.size();
    final byte[] lineNumTbl  = new byte[ ( numLineNums * 4 ) + 2 ];

    // Write line_number_table_length.
    int byteIx = 0;
    ByteArray.write16bit( numLineNums, lineNumTbl, byteIx );
    byteIx += 2;

    // Write the individual line number entries.
    for ( final MyLineNum ln : lineNums) {
        // start_pc
        ByteArray.write16bit( ln.pc, lineNumTbl, byteIx );
        byteIx += 2;
        // line_number
        ByteArray.write16bit( ln.lineNum, lineNumTbl, byteIx );
        byteIx += 2;
    }

    // Add the line number table to the CodeAttribute.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<AttributeInfo> codeAttrAttrs = codeAttr.getAttributes();
    codeAttrAttrs.removeIf( ( ai ) -> ai.getName().equals( "LineNumberTable" ) );       // remove if already present
    codeAttrAttrs.add( new AttributeInfo( constPool, "LineNumberTable", lineNumTbl ) );
}

// Attach the CodeAttribute to the MethodInfo.
minfo.setCodeAttribute( codeAttr );

// Attach the MethodInfo to the ClassFile.
try {
    classFile.addMethod( minfo );
}
catch ( final DuplicateMemberException ex ) {
    throw new AssertionError( "Caught " + ex, ex );
}
```